# mysql children in the same row of parents

Tags: mysql, group-concat, subquery

is there any way to have the schema you see here in the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af76f5) shown as:

`SKU | size S | size M | size L | init_qty | qty`

?
I was trying to use GROUP_CONCAT by it is no what I am looking for.

Here it is my query

```
select sku, name, group_concat(taglie separator ';') as `Magazzino`
from
(
  select p.sku, p.name, concat(po.valuename, ':',
  group_concat(po.value separator ',')) as taglie
  from products p
  right join products_opt po
  on p.id = po.product
  group by p.sku
) tbl
group by sku;
```

Any suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: You want to do a crosstab query on an Entity Attribute Value dataset? That's going to result in some ugly SQL.

But I have no idea what value you are expecting to see in the sizeX columns when the only value metrics (qty, init_qty) are expressed as different columns in the output.

Comment: what I am expecting is something like: 
`SKU           | size S | size M | size L |`


`demoprod |    2      |      1    |     1    |`

Comment: Thats completely different from your what you put in your question above.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `AUTO_INCREMENT` for both `id`.

### SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0bde6/2

### Needed SQL:

```
select 
    p.sku, 
    sum(po.value = 'S') as `size S`,
    sum(po.value = 'M') as `size M`,
    sum(po.value = 'L') as `size L`,
    po.product as demoproduct
from products p
right join products_opt po
on p.id = po.product
group by p.sku;
```

### Output:

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| sku   | size S | size M | size L | demoproduct |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
| PROD1 |      1 |      1 |      1 |           1 |
| PROD2 |      2 |      1 |      2 |           2 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: yes Dylan, you're right about the auto_increment. The result of your fiddle is not what I was expecting

Comment: You never mentioned what you are  expecting. I update my post based on my guessing...

Comment: sorry Dylan, my comment has been published but I hadn't finished writing it! I seem rude in my comment. I apologize. Anyway thank you very much for your new query. Why summing? Thanks for your explanation